# React component not re-rendering when useEffect dependency changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

PROBLEM:

I am currently creating a react app that allows you to checkout a book to a professor. In this app it has a couple of things that need to obviously update when a user checks out a book.

So first off there is the number of totalBooks that is checked out, or just when the entire book object changes then the component should re-render.

I have a useEffect function that is making an api call to a mongodb database and is accessing a document that will yield a book object in the response to the react app. Here is that useEffect function:

```
useEffect(() => {


        const getBook = async () => {
           
            // console.log(book)
            await api.getBookById(props.id).then(async book => {
                
                setBook({...book.data.data})

                setCopies([...book.data.data.copies])
                var num = 0;

                await book.data.data.copies.map(async (copy, index) => {
                    if(copy.checkedOut){ 
                        num++;
                        
                    }
                })

                setNumCheckedOut(num)
            }).catch(e => {console.log(e)}) 
        }

        

        getBook();
          


        
    }, [book])
```

I have even subbed out the book object dependency for something like book.checkedOutCopies. Which should return a number and if that number is different from the last then it should re-render the component. This is however, not the case. No matter what I try I am unable to re-render the component when this document changes. I even created a number called reRender and updated it when the api call to checkout a book finished its call. This would be undesired even if it worked because it would not change for someone who was already on the page, but not on the same computer as the person that clicked the checkout button.

I simply just want this component to re-render when the book object in the mongo db database has changed. Which from my understanding the right way to do it is above. The problem is that even after I successfully checkout a book the state never updates. The number of checked out books on the screen stays static:

Here is a screen shot of what the page looks like:

[image]

The green books should turn to red when the update button is clicked and a success status is responded. The Total Checked Out should also change. Neither of these happen.

Here is the book object:

```
const Book = new Schema(
    {
        bookName: { type: String, required: true },
        bookDesc: { type: String, required: false},
        numCheckedOut: { type: Number, required: false },
        copiesAvail: {type: Number},
        whosChecked: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'prof'
        }],
        copies: [Copy],
        ISBN: { type: Number, required: true },
        nextDue: {type: String},
        nextProf: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'prof'}
        
    },
    { timestamps: true },
```

)

I don't understand why it isn't updating would appreciate any help here is the file in its entirety:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import api from '../api'
import { InputGroup, Form, FormControl, Container, Button, Col, Row, Toast } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { FaBook } from 'react-icons/fa'
import BookIconFunc from '../components/helperComponents/bookIconFunc'
import Select from 'react-dropdown-select';
import './bookslist.css'
import Axios from "axios";
import BookIcoContext from '../context/BookIconContext';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import ColoredLine from '../components/helperComponents/ColoredLine'
import CheckoutBookHistroy from '../components/CheckoutBookHistory/CheckoutBookHistory'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';




const handleCheckout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}


const topLeftBook = {
    marginTop: "1.0rem",
    display: "flex",
    width:"fit-content",
    height: "fit-content",
    justifyContent: "left",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: "0px",
    border: "2px solid #73AD21",
    padding: "0.5rem 2.5rem",
}

const booksRows = {
    // marginTop: "4.0rem",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: "1.0rem",
    justifyContent: "left",
    // border: "2px solid black",
    width: "50%",
    marginLeft: "1.0rem"
    
}

const bottomForm = {
    flexGrow: "1"

}

const indBook = {
    margin: "0.5rem",
    color: "green"
}

const updateButtonStyle = {
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent:"center"
    
}

const topOfPage = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    verticalAlign: "middle" 
}

const bookIcon = {
    width: "10.0rem",
    

}

const bottomOfPage = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: "1.0rem",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    flexGrow: "1",
    marginLeft: "1.0rem"
    
}

const topForm = {
    width: "100%",
    marginLeft: "2.0rem",
    verticalAlign: "middle",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
    
    
}

export default function BooksUpdate(props) {


    /* TOP FORM VARIABLES */
    const [book, setBook] = useState(null)
    const [bookName, setBookName] = useState()
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState()
    const [ISBN, setISBN] = useState()
    const [copies, setCopies] = useState()


    const history = useHistory();




    


    /* BOOK ICON CONTEXT STATE */
    const [iconState, setIconState] = useState(false)

    /* re render state when */
    const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(0);



     /* BOTTOM FORM VARIABLES */
     const [newCopies, setNewCopies] = useState()
     const [checkoutCopiesNum, setCheckoutCopiesNum] = useState(0)
     const [numCheckedOut, setNumCheckedOut] = useState(0)
     const [allProfs, setAllProfs] = useState()
     const [profChosen, setProfChosen] = useState()
     const [bookicoref, setIcoRefs] = useState([]);
     const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState(new Date());

     var anotherRender = 0;




    const submitCheckout = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          
          
          const checkoutBookData = {book, checkoutCopiesNum, profChosen, dueDate};
          
       
          const checkoutBookRes = await Axios.post("http://localhost:8174/api/book/checkout/" + props.id, checkoutBookData)
          if(checkoutBookRes.statusText === 'OK'){
            setShowCheckoutToast(!showCheckoutToast)
          }
          /* Display toast that confirms the book was checked out */
          setReRender(reRender+1)
          anotherRender = anotherRender + 1
        // history.push("/Books/Update/" + props.id)
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
        
    }

    const handleSetBook = (bookData) => {
        setBook({...bookData})
    }



    useEffect(() => {


        const getBook = async () => {
           
            // console.log(book)
            await api.getBookById(props.id).then(async book => {
                await handleSetBook(book.data.data)
                // setBook(book.data.data)

                setCopies([...book.data.data.copies])
                var num = 0;

                await book.data.data.copies.map(async (copy, index) => {
                    if(copy.checkedOut){ 
                        num++;
                        
                    }
                })

                setNumCheckedOut(num)
            }).catch(e => {console.log(e)}) 
        }

        

        getBook();
          


        
    }, [book])

    useEffect( () => {

        const getProfs = async () => {

            await Axios.get('http://localhost:8174/user/professors').then((ps) => {
                var array = []

                ps.data.data.map((prof, index) => {
                    array.push({label: prof.name, value: prof, key: prof._id})
                })
                setAllProfs(array)

            })
            
        }

        getProfs()

    }, [])


    

    


    /* EFFECT TO CREATE REFS FOR EACH BOOK ICON */
    useEffect(() => {
        
        // add or remove refs
        copies &&
        setIcoRefs(bookicorefs => (
          Array(copies.length).fill().map((_, i) => bookicorefs[i] || React.createRef())
        ))
    }, [copies]);





    

    const handleUpdate = () => {
        console.log("handling update")
    }

    
    


    const findCheckedOut = (array) => {
        var numChecked = 0;
 
        array.filter(arr => {
            if(arr.checkedOut){
                numChecked = numChecked + 1
            }
              
        })
     

        return numChecked
    }

    const [showCheckoutToast, setShowCheckoutToast] = useState(false)


    const toggleCheckToast = () => {
        setShowCheckoutToast(!showCheckoutToast)
    }



   

    


    /* EFFECT TO VALIDATE THE INFORMATION INSIDE THE CHECKOUT BOOKS FIELD */
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!copies){
          return   
        }

        if(checkoutCopiesNum > copies.length){
            alert("There isn't that much of this book available")
            return;
        }
        // console.log(numCheckedOut)
        if(checkoutCopiesNum > (copies.length - numCheckedOut)){
            setCheckoutCopiesNum(0)
            alert('You cannot checkout that many copies as there is already to many checked out')
            return;
        }


        // for(var i = 0; i < checkoutCopiesNum; i++){

        // }
        

    },[checkoutCopiesNum, numCheckedOut])




    return (
        book ? 
        copies ?
        <div>
        <Container>
            {/* Show the book icon with the title of the book underneath */}
            

            <div style={topOfPage}>
                <div style={topLeftBook}>
            
                    <FaBook style={bookIcon} size={200}/>
                    <h4 className="">{book.bookName}</h4>
                    
                </div>

                <Form style={topForm}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col className="pl-0">
                            <InputGroup className="mb-3 mt-3">
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">Book Name</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <FormControl onChange={(e) => setBookName(e.target.value)}
                                    defaultValue={book.bookName}
                                    aria-label="Name"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                                
                                <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={5} defaultValue={book.bookDesc}/>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>


                        <Col className="m-0 pr-0">
                            <InputGroup className="mb-4 mt-3">
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">ISBN</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <FormControl onChange={(e) => setISBN(e.target.value)}
                                    defaultValue={book.ISBN}
                                    aria-label="Name"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            <InputGroup className="mb-4 mt-4">
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">Total Copies</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <FormControl onChange={(e) => setNewCopies(e.target.value)}
                                
                                    aria-label="Name"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                    defaultValue={copies.length}
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">Total Checked Out</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <FormControl onChange={(e) => setNewCopies(e.target.value)}
                                    
                                    aria-label="Name"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                    defaultValue={findCheckedOut(book.copies)}
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            
                            
                        </Col>
                        <Button style={updateButtonStyle} onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</Button>
                    </Row>
                    
                </Form>
            </div>




            <Row style={{justifyContent: "space-between", verticalAlign: "middle"}}>
            
            <Toast 
                show={showCheckoutToast} 
                onClose={toggleCheckToast} 
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                }}
            
            
            
            >
                <Toast.Header>
                    <img
                    src="holder.js/20x20?text=%20"
                    className="rounded mr-2"
                    alt=""
                    />
                    <strong className="mr-auto">Success!</strong>
                </Toast.Header>
                <Toast.Body>Successfully Checked out a Book</Toast.Body>
            </Toast>

            

                <div style={bottomOfPage}>
                    <Form style={bottomForm} onSubmit={submitCheckout}>
                        <InputGroup className="mt-4">
                        <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon4">Checkout Out Copies:</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                
                                <FormControl
                                    onChange={(e) => setCheckoutCopiesNum(e.target.value)}
                                    placeholder={checkoutCopiesNum}
                                    aria-label="Name"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                />
                        </InputGroup>

                        <Select
                            className="mt-4"
                            style={{width: "100%"}}
                            name="Select"
                            required
                            // loading
                            searchable
                            placeholder="To:"
                            options={allProfs}
                            onChange={(values) => {setProfChosen(values[0].value)}}
                        />
                        

                     
                        <DatePicker className="mt-4" selected={dueDate} onChange={date => setDueDate(date)} />
                      
                        
                        <Button type="submit" className="mt-3 w-100">Checkout</Button>

                    </Form>
                    
                </div>



                <BookIcoContext.Provider value={{iconState, setIconState}}>
                    <div style={booksRows} onClick={() => setIconState(true)} onMouseUp={() => setIconState(false)}>
                        {
                            
                            copies ? copies.map((copy, index) => {
                                return <div 
                                key={index}  
                                >
                                    <BookIconFunc 
                                        checkedOut={copy.checkedOut}
                                        ref={bookicoref[index]} 
                                    >
                                    </BookIconFunc>
                                </div>
                            }) 
                        
                        : 
                        
                        
                            <div>none</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </BookIcoContext.Provider>
            </Row>
            


         
            
        </Container>
            <ColoredLine color="grey" m={20} height={1}/>
            <Container>
                {/* {book.whosChecked.map(prof => {
                    // console.log(prof)
                    // <Col>{prof}</Col>
                })} */}
                <CheckoutBookHistroy book_id={props.id} book={book} reRender={reRender}></CheckoutBookHistroy>
            </Container>
        </div>

        :

        <div>no data</div>

        :
        <div>no data</div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Can you give a link to codesandbox or someplace where this can be reproduced?

Comment: The type of functionality I want would be that of a stream.. @shivamragnar I would need someway to stream the data so that each instance of the app updates with an update to the items in the database

Comment: Hey @devin that is totally fine, the kind of functionality that you wanna develop. But to fix your issue, there needs to be a reproducible link where, it can be debugged.

Comment: You could clone the repository. Its currently private, aber i just need a MERN stack way of having a realtime application.